# Batch - Passing variable from subroutine to subroutine error

Tags: variables, batch-file, call, subroutine

Main_Control is the parent batch.
It calls batches named DEFAULT, SETOPTIONS AND USEROPTIONS.
DEFAULT sets a variable %def_set% to either 1 or 2.  %def_set% is used in USEROPITONS to set some other variables which are used in SETOPITONS.  After DEFAULT, in the MAIN_CONTROL, a test of %def_set% returns error "'1' (or '2') is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch" for both %def_set%=1 or 2.  It doesn't seem to pass the variable correctly.  What have I done wrong?

------------------------CODE-------------------------

"Main_Control" = batch1

```
@ECHO off 
CLS
MODE CON:cols=130 lines=75


REM This particular file is the control script which CALLs the subroutines to perform the back or restore of settings. 
:skipintro

REM 1. Get backup location and subroutine location/names.
REM 2. Clear screen
REM 3. Display the notes text file in the window (must be paused).
REM 4. Pause to read notes
REM 4. Get user name
REM 6. "START1" label.  Start point if the user wants to rerun backup/restore in same session.
REM 7. Ask if user wants to backup or restore
REM 8. Ask what settings to backup/restore
REM 9. Ask if the user wants to use default settings
REM 10. If user wants to change default settings, provide options to change.
REM 11. Set the options to use throughout the backup/restore.

CALL "%~DP0"_BackupLocation_Subroutines.bat
CLS
TYPE %NOTES%
Timeout /t 30
CALL %GETUSERNAME%

:START1
CALL %B_R_OPTION%
CALL %MENU%
CALL %DEFAULTS%
rem test1
echo before & %def_set% & pause
rem END TEST1
CALL %USEROPTIONS%
REM TEST2
echo  after & %def_set% & pause
REM END TEST2   
CALL %SETOPTIONS%

Echo You are back in %~n0.
Echo You chose action: %ACTION%
Echo You chose to %ACTION%: %SELECTION%
Timeout /T 5

:: Create (for backups) or verify existence (for restores) the Main Backup and Registry Folders.
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET FOLDERS= ^
%BACKUP_FOLDER% ^
%REGISTRY_FOLDER%

IF %ACTION%==Backup CALL %CREATE%
IF %ACTION%==Restore CALL %VERIFY%

ETC ETC ETC
```

%DEF_set% has to pass from DEFAULTS to USEROPTIONS and SETOPTIONS.  But it is not.

DEFAULTS batch

```
@echo off

REM  Name:  DEFAULTS

REM  Asks user to use defaults and have no more prompts or to be prompted for inputs.

:def_input
CLS
ECHO Would you like to use default values?
ECHO    Backup location:  %Backup_Folder%   (cannot modify at this time)
ECHO    Overwrite previous backup:      No
ECHO    Rename previous backup with date/time:  Yes
ECHO    Prompt to overwrite files:      No  (no option to change)
ECHO    Prompt to delete files:         No
ECHO    Generate a log:             Yes
ECHO    Overwrite or append to an existing log: Overwrite
ECHO    Log file located in backup location:    Yes (no option to change)   
ECHO.
ECHO  1. Yes
ECHO  2. No
ECHO.
Set /P Def_SET= Choose:  
ECHO.
FOR %%w in (1 2) DO IF #%Def_SET%==#%%w (
    ECHO You selected: %Def_SET%
    Timeout /T 5
    Exit /b
    )


REM USER ERROR
REM If the user types something other than 1 or 2, the FOR/DO/IF statement won't run indicating user error. 
REM The routine will continue here, letting the user know there is an error.
ECHO Error
ECHO Select 1 or 2 & GOTO :def_input
```

After this, TEST1 in Main_control batch returns this error "'1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch".

USEROPTIONS batch

```
@echo off
REM  Name:  USEROPTIONS
ECHO %~no & %def_set% & pause
IF %def_set%==1 GOTO :defopts
IF %def_set%==2 GOTO :askopts

:defopts

:: Overwrite previous backup
SET OW_BU=1

:: Generate a log
SET ONLog=1

:: Overwrite the log
SET OWLog=1

:: Prompt to delete files
SET Del_P=1

GOTO :EOF

:askopts
::              Questions to Users
::           Overwrite Backup Question
:: Rename the previous backup if user does not want it overwritten.
:OW_Backup
IF NOT EXIST %BACKUP_FOLDER%\ GOTO :skipOWQ
REM If previous backup does not exist, skip question to overwrite it.

ECHO.
ECHO Do you want to OVERWRITE the previous backup.  Choose:
ECHO  1. Do not overwrite old backup,then rename it with its "created" date.
ECHO  2. Overwrite old backup.
ECHO.   
SET /P OW_BU= Make a selection...
FOR %%u in (1 2) DO IF #%OW_BU%==#%%u (
    ECHO You selected: %OW_BU%
    GOTO SkipError1
    )
REM Error
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO *********Error*************
ECHO Select 1 or 2 & GOTO :OW_Backup
:SkipError1
:skipOWQ        

::              Generate Robocopy Log

:GenLog
ECHO.
ECHO Do you want to GENERATE a Robocopy log?
ECHO It will be located in %Backup_Folder%.
ECHO  1. Yes
ECHO  2. No
ECHO.   
SET /P ONLog= Make a selection...
FOR %%v in (1 2) DO IF #%ONLog%==#%%v (
    ECHO You selected: %ONLog%
    GOTO SkipError2
    )
REM Error
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO *********Error*************
ECHO Select 1 or 2 & GOTO :GenLog
:SkipError2

::          Overwrite or Append Robocopy Log
IF %ONLog%==2 GOTO :Del_Prompt
:OW_RLog
ECHO.
 ECHO Do you want to OVERWRITE the Robocopy log?
ECHO. 
ECHO  1. Yes - Overwrite
ECHO  2. No - Append to Log
ECHO.   
SET /P ONLog= Make a selection...
FOR %%v in (1 2) DO IF #%ONLog%==#%%v (
    ECHO You selected: %ONLog%
    GOTO SkipError3
    )
 REM Error
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO *********Error*************
ECHO Select 1 or 2 & GOTO :OW_Rlog
:SkipError3

::          Prompt to Delete Decision
:Del_Prompt
ECHO.
 ECHO.
 ECHO The restoration will delete default files that are not in your backup in order to restore your VDI to the way you had it.
ECHO Do you want confirmations to delete files?
 ECHO  1.  No confirmations to delete files.
ECHO  2.  Review and confirm to delete files.
ECHO.
 SET /P Del_P= Make a selection...
ECHO.
FOR %%x in (1 2) DO IF #%Del_P%==#%%x (
    ECHO You selected: %Del_P%
    GOTO SkipError4
    )
REM Error
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO *********Error*************
ECHO Select 1 or 2 & GOTO :Del_Prompt
:SkipError4

Exit /b
```

Back to Main_Control batch, then call SETOPTIONS
SETOPTIONS batch

```
@echo off

REM  Name:  SETOPTIONS

ECHO Currenlty running: %~nx0
pause

::              Set Options


ECHO Backup location is: %Backup_Folder%
REM Test
echo OnLog %Onlog%
echo Overwrite %Overwrite%
echo Del_P %del_P%
pause 


:://///////////////////////   Robocopy options    /////////////////////////////
IF %ONLog%==1 (
   IF %OWLog%==1 SET LOG=/LOG:%BACKUP_FOLDER%\Robocopy_Log.txt
    IF %OWLog%==2 SET LOG=/LOG+:%BACKUP_FOLDER%\Robocopy_Log.txt 
    ) else (
        SET LOG=
        )
SET R_OPT=/Z /MIR %LOG%
REM Removed /copyall


:://///////////////////  Overwrite Backup Code  ////////////////////////////////
 IF NOT EXIST %BACKUP_FOLDER%\ GOTO :skipOWC

IF %Overwrite%== 1 (
    ECHO.
    ECHO %BACKUP_FOLDER% will be RENAMED.
    TIMEOUT /T 2
    Call %RENAME% 
    )

IF %Overwrite%== 2 (
    Echo %BACKUP_FOLDER% will be OVERWRITTEN. 
    ECHO Close this window if you've changed your mind.
    TIMEOUT /T 10 
    )   

REM Nothing to do to overwrite old backup.  It will do it on its own with /MIR option.
:skipOWC

:://///////////////////  Prompt to Delete Code   ////////////////////////////////
IF %Del_P%== 1 SET Del_Opt_Prompt=/Q
IF %Del_P%== 2 SET DEL_Opt_Prompt=/P
DEL_OPT=/F /S %Del_Opt_Prompt%

REM Test
echo OnLog %Onlog%
echo Overwrite %Overwrite%
echo Del_P %del_P%
pause 

EXIT /b
```

And back to Main_Control batch.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `&` ampersand character (this one to be *displayed*) using a `^` caret as follows:

```
echo before ^& %def_set% & pause
rem END TEST1
CALL %USEROPTIONS%
REM TEST2
echo  after ^& %def_set% & pause
```

The `&` ampersand is [one of a few with special meaning](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in a Window CLI and/or batch.

Read also [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html).

Answer (score 0):

So many errors and typos.
In trying to figure out why the called batches weren't working, I added more errors in my attempts to test it.
The tests in Main_Control contained ampersands.

```
echo before & %def_set% & pause
```

USEROPTIONS crashed because of a typo - letter "o" instead of zero "0" in:

```
ECHO %~no & %def_set% & pause
```

SETOPTIONS crashed because I forgot what variables I was using. %overwrite% doesn't describe anything and doesn't exist in the line:

```
echo Overwrite %Overwrite%
```

It should have been :

```
echo Overwrite backup OW_BU = %OW_BU%
echo Overwrite log OWlog = %OWlog%
```

SET was ommitted from the beginning of the line:

```
DEL_OPT=/F /S %Del_Opt_Prompt%
```

And i think that solved all my problems.  What a waste of yesterday staring at this all day.  In short, the calls worked & the variables were being passed from subroutine to subroutine.  The errors were all typos initially and made even worse when I introduced more typos into my attempts to tests and trap errors.  I'm tired of this project.